# parameterization of the graph $y=x^2$ from (-2,4) to (1,1)

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametrization

I need to integrate a vector field over C which is described as the graph $y=x^2$ from (-2, 4) to (1, 1). Do I treat $y=x^2$ as a line segment from (-2, 4) to (1, 1), so that the parameterization is $$<-2+3t, 4-3t>$$ for $t\in[0,1]$?

Comment: No: This is not a line segment.....

Comment: $(t,t^2)$ for $t\in[-2,1]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to let $ x=t$ and $ y= t^2$ for $-2\le t \le 1$

The parametrization that you have introduced does not consider the curve as a parabola.

Comment: What if it's from (1,1) to (-2,4) instead?

Comment: @sucksatmath in that case let $x=-t$ and $y=t^2$ and let $-1\le t \le2$

Answer (score 0):

*Any* function graph $y = f(x)$ can be parametrized as $(x,f(x))$ with $x\in\cdots$.